# Type for mapping typescript union to fixed values

Tags: typescript, types, type-definition

If I have a type like the below and I want to map it to some fixed values at compile time, I can do the following:

```
type MyType = {
  a: string;
  b: string;
}

const MyMapping: { [k in keyof MyType]: number } = {
  a: 3,
  b: 2,
}

type X = typeof MyMapping['a'] // Should be 3
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiAq5oF4oG8CwAoKUCGAXFAM7ABOAlgHYDmA3NrgEZGmW0NYC+22AxgHsqpWCBh4wYajSJooAbQDWUalEUQQAgGajEkALpEqAVwC2TCGShcoqTDnxEAzABpGUFlABMb7ryygkFAAGrZQgRDaouKS0vIA5Hjx+lAA9KlQAMoAFgLGADYAJh7QTkA)

Is there a way I can do the same for a union of existing types?

```
type MyType = {
  a: string;
  b: string;
}

const MyMapping: /* Magic type here */ = {
  a: 3,
  b: 2,
}

type X = typeof MyMapping['a'] // Should be 3
```

I realize this probably won't work in the exact form I have up there, but is there some other way to format this to make this happen?

Comment: Please correct the code, I think you mean you can do `const MyMapping : { [k in keyof MyType] : number } = {
  a: 3,
  b: 2,
}` But it's hard to tell your intent without valid code

Comment: Your last code sample makes no sense, how do you want `MyMappedTyped` to be created? Is it of type `{a: a, b: b}` (where `a` and `b` types are defined as `type * = number`)? Then just construct this mapping manually. How is it related to union at all? Your union doesn't have `a` or `b` keys.

Answer (score 1):

First off, we can simplify `{[k in keyof MyType] : number}` to be just `Record<keyof MyType, number>` (basically the same type just using the predefined mapped type `Record`)

If you are using typescript 4.9 or later, you ca use the `satisfies` operator to constrain the type of the variable while still lettig the compiler infer the type. Coupled with an `as const` to preserve the literal types, we get the desired result:

```
const MyMapping = {
  a: 3,
  b: 2,
} as const satisfies Record<keyof MyType, number>
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiAq5oF4oG8CwAoKUCGAXFAM7ABOAlgHYDmA3NrgEZGmW0NYC+22AxgHsqpWCBh4wYajSipMOfEQDMAGkZQWUAExru+YlEHDgJPMArEAZhQgGAShEFkAJgB4A1hBADLoxJBUoKgBXAFsmCDIAPl4sUEgoAA1ZKHiIH1FxSWkAbQByPDyAXSgAelKoJWwgA)

If you are using a version of typescript before 4.9, you can still do this using an identity function to allow inference to happen but also constrain the type of the object literal:

```
function makeMap<T extends Record<keyof MyType, V>, V extends number>(o: T & Record<Exclude<keyof T, keyof MyType>, never>) {
  return o
}

const MyMapping = makeMap({
  a: 3,
  b: 2,
  c: 1
})

type X = typeof MyMapping['a'] // 3
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=6&ssc=123&pln=6&pc=78#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiAq5oF4oG8CwAoKUCGAXFAM7ABOAlgHYDmA3NrgEZGmW0NYC+22AZgFcqAY2AUA9lSgBbPAGsIMPGAA88KBAAewCFQAmxKACUIw8WT0qFIcX1gIkAGigA1AHzOXG7boNQqAtJMEGRuABTiROoAZMam5pYAoprCADYCehBWEDZ28M7WtvaIkB7+EABuIW4AlOiMUGQQwAJkUuLYPFjYZlSk9kpgYNQ0UKiyCoNhmDj4RADMjg0sUABMS7PCRACMnTW8WKCQUAAaY1BHEEVwg8O0ANoA5HiPALpQAPQfUPPYQA)

There are a few tricks to the function:

1. The `V` type parameter is used to force TypeScript to infer number literals for the values in the object instead of `number`
2. `Record<Exclude<keyof T, keyof MyType>, never>` is used to prevent excess properties (this is because we don't get excess property checks when we assign to a type parameter)